# How many students will I know?

Tags: combinatorics

I entered my school in Class $6$, and am currently in Class $9$. When I gave the Class $8$ exams, I was wondering if I could find out how many students I would know in my future class. So, I made some sort of table, but that got too complicated. So I got this approach:

> I am in Class $6$. Each Class has $7$ Sections. Each Section has $49$ students. I know everyone in my Section, and no one else. On the first day of each class, I know those people who were with me in previous sections. At the end of the year, I know everyone in my section. Everyone passes the exams. There are no fails, new admissions, or removals. Only $7$ persons can go to a section from the same class. How many students will I know in Class $9$?

I know every student in Class $6$ Section 'G'. When everyone is promoted to Class $7$, $7$ random students from each class will go to a particular section. Assume I am $1$.

So, I know $2,3,4,...,49$. When we are promoted, let $1,8,15,22,29,36,43$ go to $'A'$. So, in Class $7$ Section $A$, on the first day, I know only $8, 15, 22,29,36$ and $43$. Let the other students in $7A$ be $A_1,A_2,...,A_{42}$. At first, I will not know them. At the end of the year, I will know all of them.

So, when we get promoted to Class $8$, $6$ others from $7A$ will also be in say $8B$. Let $1,A_1,A_2,...,A_6$ be sent to $8B$. So, in $8B$, I will know $6$ people who are also from $7A$.

But, of the people from $6G$ who were sent to the sections $7B$ to $7G$, i.e. $2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,31,32,33,34,35,37,38,39,40,41,42,44,45,46,47,48,49$ some will certainly be transferred to $8B$ too.

So, in addition to $A_1,A_2,...,A_6$, I will also know, say, $3,25, 45,23,11,26$, who were transferred elsewhere in $7$ but were then transferred to $8B$.

Continuing, I want to know that ***How many students will I know in my first day of Class 9?***